# Evaluate() in VBA

Tags: vba, excel, debugging, expression-evaluation

Hi and welcome to the [Evaluate()](http://www.google.co.uk/?q=Evaluate%28%29%20VBA) mystery

---

The MSDN Office Developer Reference (2013) Documentation says:

> Using square brackets (for example, "[A1:C5]") is identical to calling
>   the Evaluate method with a string argument.

---

So, I have ran a very simple code to see how accurate the [Microsoft's Documentation of the Evaluate()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff838386.aspx) method is. 
Not surprisingly, I am getting a strange albeit consistent result.
***note:*** *execute each of the 4 commands in the `Immediate Window` <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>. See the difference in each of the calls*. Notice the built-in ***bug*** which ***shows each MsgBox twice***. Just keep that in mind and do not get confused...
Stick this code in a module

```
Private Sub SleepESub()
    Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("0:00:20")
    MsgBox "w8'd "
End Sub
```

then execute these 4 commands ( 1 at a time ) in the Immediate Window

`? Evaluate ("SleepESub()")`
`? [SleepESub()]`
`? [SleepESub]`
`? SleepESub`

The first 2 execute the code right away; means to me they have evaluated the code. The third one *(according to the documentation)* should be *`Evaluating`* but it doesn't act the same way *as it does in a module's body*. The Immediate Window is giving an `Error 2023` however the same call from within a module's body executes it as if you were calling a sub.It waits the *`20 seconds`* like if it was a normal `Call SleepESub()` which is the number 4 call. 

Can anyone explain what I am missing here? Is the line number 3 not a proper `Evaluation` call? or does it evaluate the call to sub itself (if that makes sense)

Update:
I think some people are misunderstanding what I am evaluating here - don't worry it is an advanced topic and I am not a book writer and you are not mind readers. (*forgive me...*)

To get a better idea you can compare results from the immediate window vs. module's body. Try this code:

```
' Run each of the calls separately
' in a module's body and compare it with 
' the previous calls from the Immediate Window
    Sub ModuleBody()
        Evaluate ("SleepESub()")
        '[SleepESub()]
        '[SleepESub]
        'SleepESub
    End Sub
```

Comment: interesting. i need to remove the `?` for the last two. `Run("SleepESub")` and `Run("SleepESub()")` are similar but `Evaluate("SleepESub")` doesn't work. What's going on?!

Comment: With Excel 2010 (_Evaluate_ doc is same as 2013), `? Evaluate("SleepESub")` returns `Error 2029` ; same for `? [SleepESub]`. I would conclude that 2010 is "clean" (matches the documentation)

Comment: @d-stroyer `? [SleepESub]` (*called from the Immediate Window*) does return a `Error 2029`, however If you make the same call within a module's body it does work, although is not Evaluating it just executes as if you were calling a sub. I am starting to wonder if the square brackets are just being ignored in this case as the compiler *thinks* `[SleepESub] = SleepyESub`. On the other hand, if the Immediate Window is giving an error how come the same call from a modules body works?

Comment: If you change the declaration of SleepESub to make it `Public`, then `[SleepESub]` works from the Immediate Window. Same result as from module's body (no apparent evaluation).

Comment: `Expected function or variable.` error appears even in case when its not made private in *Excel 2010*. I dont think it's the visibility issue. Also, I am not sure why I am getting an error but it works for you :o

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It would appear to me that what differs in the different ways of executing the code would be the thread that it runs on - the UI thread or a background thread, and the parser.  `Evaluate` executed functions would be handled differently to explicitly defined functions, and functions called from the Immediate window would be handled slightly differently also.

In:

```
Sub ModuleBody()
    Evaluate ("SleepESub()")
    [SleepESub()]
    [SleepESub]
    SleepESub
End Sub
```

`Evaluate ("SleepESub()")` and  `[SleepESub()]` appear to be expecting a formula, and `Private Sub SleepESub()` is not being executed at all.

Depending on how the parser handles the procedure, each command may be executed in sequence in a single thread, resulting in the delay from the `Application.Wait`, or the `Application.Wait` may be considered to be valid only on the UI thread, and skipped when run on a background thread.

This can be confirmed by the following code, executed by `?[SleepESub()]` or `?Evaluate("SleepESub()")` in the Immediate window:

```
Private Declare PtrSafe Sub sapiSleep Lib "kernel32" Alias "Sleep" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long)
Private Sub SleepESub()
    'Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("0:00:05")
    sapiSleep 5000
    MsgBox "w8'd "
End Sub
```

When using the `sapiSleep 5000` API call, the wait occurs (twice! - that bug that was mentioned), but when using `Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("0:00:05")`, no delay occurs.

Comment: You are right! I was wrong assuming the the first two calls have been evaluated, they were not - they were partially executed. The `Application.Wait` was omitted even though the msgbox was shown it did not execute the `SleepESub` properly. It does make a difference calling the `ModuleBody` from the Module vs. the Immediate Window. It's worth mentioning that the `[SleepESub] = SleepESub`.

Comment: Actually, in Evaluate ("SleepESub()") and [SleepESub()], Private Sub SleepESub() is not being executed at all - try setting breakpoints on both the Sub ModuleBody() and Private Sub SleepESub() lines, and you'll see when you single-step through the code that Private Sub SleepESub() is not hit on these two lines in ModuleBody().

Answer (score -1):

I think that it is wrong to state that the 3rd call is not evaluating : it does indeed evaluate the provided object, and return its value (as documented).

I have slightly modified the Sub to illustrate:

```
Private Function SleepESub()
    Debug.Print Application.Wait(Now + TimeValue("0:00:02"))
    MsgBox "w8'd "
    SleepESub = 42
End Function
```

Each of the 4 evaluation calls will indeed return 42 as expected.

What is different is:

- the application context (in one case the call to `Application.Wait`
  succeeds, in the other it fails - notice the debug output which
  returns either true or false)
- the number of calls to the routine (one or two calls)

I have no explanation for either of these differences, though.