# Need guidance with a VBA function to paste values in Excel

Tags: function, vba, excel

I'm a VBA newbie, but have successfully created a handful of useful Excel Functions. The one I'm working on right now, which seems like it should be simple, is eluding me. I think I'm misunderstanding the syntax, and need some guidance.

Consider the following screen capture; I am attempting to create the function in Column E, which is simply the VALUE from D$n.
[image]

So far, this is as far as I've gotten:

```
Function PASTVALUE(q As String)
q.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
End Function
```

which, if I understand properly, is reading the input value (in my case, the contents of cell `D$n`) as a String, then pasting it using `PasteValues`.

Do I need to somehow copy it before I paste it? I thought that the `q As String` parameter was what brought it into the function.

But then if I'm not copying, is it trying to `paste` from an empty clipboard...in which case I have *no* idea what I should be using to accomplish this.

Help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just ''transfer'' the value(displayed) over like this

```
Function PASTEVALUE(rng As Range)
    PASTEVALUE = rng.Text
End Function
```

or use the [Evaluate()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17484571/evaluate-eval-in-vba) function to evaluate the formula in that range

```
 Function PASTEVALUE(rng As Range)
        PASTEVALUE = [rng]
    End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

There are some features of Excel's object model that you cannot access during a calculation; i.e. during the evaluation of a function. Broadly speaking they are the ones that manipulate the value in cells in some way. If the converse were true, then the calculation process in Excel would break.

Pasting clipboard data into the worksheet falls therefore into the forbidden category.

One solution would be to put your code in a macro; accessible by a button on the worksheet. That is outside the calculation cycle and therefore permissible.